# Python Azure authentication

Tags: python, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I am trying to connect to azure in the same spirt that I am doing on Windows PowerShell.

**Command:**
`Connect-AzureAD -TenantId "xxxxxxxx-59ed-466e-8759-03044xxx46197" -AccountId  "xxxxxxxx-8d16-474a-a795-ddef8ea410e3" -AadAccessToken "xxxxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx"`

**Output:**

```
Account                              Environment TenantId                             TenantDomain                         AccountType
-------                              ----------- --------                             ------------                         -----------
xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx AzureCloud  xxxxxx-59ed-466e-xx59-030448046197 5e0b361b-59ed-466e-8759-xxxxxxxxxx AccessToken
```

So above works but would like to do the same with python.

The docs are all over the place with mapping client_id to application_id and such.

Does anyone have a way to connect with python with the same information from the above command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the MSAL for Python package. You can find MSAL Python on Pypi.

```
pip install msal
```

Acquiring tokens with MSAL Python follows this 3-step pattern. This is the high level conceptual pattern. There will be some variations for different flows.

They are demonstrated in the [runnable samples](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/tree/dev/sample).

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/active-directory?view=azure-python

Comment: {
    "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID",
    "client_id": "ACCOUNT_ID",
    "scope": ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"],
    "secret": "AD_ACCESS_TOKEN",
    "endpoint": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
}. Here is the mapping. The links you provided didn't really have a direct mapping but it did help with messing around till I got it to work. Thanks !